# Airdropped video missing on iphone 5

Tags: video, airdrop

My husband airdropped a video to me. I accepted, it showed the download timer, when finished, I looked for it, but can't find it anywhere in my phone. My husband went to try to send it to me again and it's also missing on his phone. Where did the video go?!

Comment: Consider helping us help you. What OS device sent the file? What version of iOS received the file? Were both signed in to the same iCloud account? How AirDrop works depend on these details. Take a pass at editing this after you've read the [help guide](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to be specific and show how your research didn't help you solve this dilemma.